# JSON and Greek letters

Tags: php, json

I am successfully posting data(using Greek language) in my database,and I can display them in my CMS without any problems. However,when I read them as JSON for later android use,I get something like this.

```
[{"id":"7","name":"\u0391. \u0392\u03ad\u03c1\u03c4\u03b6\u03b9\u03bf\u03c2",
 "age":"32","number":"5",
"position":"\u0391\u03bc\u03c5\u03bd\u03c4\u03b9\u03ba\u03cc\u03c2","image":"vertzios.jpg","teams":"\u039d\u03af\u03ba\u03b7 \u0392\u03cc\u03bb\u03bf\u03c5"}]
```

In other words,I can not see the Greek letters.

This is my code for getting JSON

```
<?php 
 include("../includes/connect.php");
$string="";
$get_posts = "select * from defenders";

$run_posts = mysqli_query($con,$get_posts); 

 $posts_array = array();

 while ($posts_row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_posts)){


               $row_array['id'] = $posts_row['id'];
               $row_array['name'] = $posts_row['name'];
               $row_array['age'] = $posts_row['age'];
               $row_array['number'] = $posts_row['number'];
               $row_array['position'] = $posts_row['position'];

               $row_array['image'] = $posts_row['image'];
               $row_array['teams'] = $posts_row['teams'];

                array_push($posts_array,$row_array);

 }

   $string = json_encode($posts_array);

   echo $string;

?>
```

Do I need to do some kind of decoding? In my connection file I used this

```
mysqli_set_charset($con,'utf8');
```

Thanks

Comment: I put $string = json_encode($posts_array,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); but I get letters that make no sense Ξ. ΞΞ­ΟΟΞΆΞΉΞΏΟ.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `decodeURI()` to convert them. Consider this:

```
"position": "\u0391\u03bc\u03c5\u03bd\u03c4\u03b9\u03ba\u03cc\u03c2"
```

Now, the `decodeURI()` will do:

```
decodeURI("\u0391\u03bc\u03c5\u03bd\u03c4\u03b9\u03ba\u03cc\u03c2")
"Αμυντικός"
```

It is really good that JSON is not getting affected. Because, this is UTF-8 characters, the `json_encode` will not work for them and throw an error. I had also wrote in the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php#115980), how to handle those stuff:

> I used this simple script, flicked from StackOverflow to escape from the function failing:
>
> ```
> <?php
>     function utf8ize($d) {
>         if (is_array($d)) {
>             foreach ($d as $k => $v) {
>                 $d[$k] = utf8ize($v);
>             }
>         } else if (is_string ($d)) {
>             return utf8_encode($d);
>         }
>         return $d;
>     }
> ?>
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,but how should I use that on my code? I am bit confused on that.

Comment: @Theo You should use in the JavaScript. So when you are setting the HTML or Text from the JSON, use `decodeURI(data)`, may be?

Comment: Oh God! I am not really experienced with Javascript. Is there another way?

Comment: @Theo Show your code? May be I can help you with it.